# Condensing Data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I have roughly 1000 rows of data, and each day has about 50-60 rows for it. Is there a way I can condense it to where it will just say "May 20" and if you click it, you can get all of the data to pop up? Its annoying to have to scroll all the way down every time I want to add something.

Comment: There are a number of ways to go about this. Sharing a link to the spreadsheet or to a copy of it will help in talking about solutions. Solutions are built around specifics, and right now, all we have is a general question the answer to which is "Yes, there is a way."

Comment: "Its annoying to have to scroll all the way down every time I want to add something." ... a solution could be to ALWAYS have the first row (let's say A2: 2) free, leaving a script to move all the data to the last free row